# How do I prove this greatest common divisor problem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Let $n\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}\!,\;k \in (\mathbb{Z}_n,+),\;\text{and}\;d=\gcd(k,n)$.

Prove that $\langle k \rangle = \langle d \rangle$.

Not sure how to prove this one, any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\langle k \rangle$ and $\langle d \rangle$ denote the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ generated by $k,d$ respectively.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&d= \gcd(k,n)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&d|k\\[4pt]
\implies\;&k=dx,\;\text{for some integer $x$}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&k\in \langle d \rangle\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\langle k \rangle \subseteq \langle d \rangle\\[10pt]
\text{Also,}\;\;&d=\gcd(k,n)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&ak + bn = d,\;\text{for some integers $a,b$}\;\,\text{[by Bezout's Theorem]}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&ak \equiv d\;(\text{mod}\; n)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&d\in \langle k \rangle\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\langle d \rangle \subseteq \langle k \rangle\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Therefore $\langle k \rangle = \langle d \rangle,\;$as was to be shown.